# mysql create a trigger in a database listening to table changes in a different database

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER
       schema1.triggername
AFTER INSERT ON schema2.table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
       ;
END;
```

ERROR 1435 (HY000): Trigger in wrong schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trigger needs to be in the same schema as the table you are inserting to, but it can access tables in other schemas.

Using your example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER schema2.triggername
AFTER INSERT ON schema2.the_table
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO schema1.the_table values (...);
```

Comment: yes, thanks but I want the trigger (all the triggers actually) in a different schema than the tables.

Comment: this fixed my error after using create trigger schema2.triggername